# Javascript native set date between midnight

Tags: javascript, date

Am currently setting mu dates manually like this

```
  public selectedMoments = [
   new Date(2018, 2, 15, 0, 0,0),
   new Date(2018, 2, 15, 24, 0,0)
 ];
```

The above sets the datepicker date to be between

```
   15 jan 2018 12:00AM
   16 jan 2018 12:00AM
```

Now i wouldlike to continue the same way but not setting it manually.
So the date should be covering the previous entire day. That is

```
if today is wednesday
between tuesday 00:00 and wednesday 00:00
```

I have tried

```
  public selectedMoments = [
   new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)),
   new Date(new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0))
 ];
```

THe above sets between wednesday and thursday

Comment: You'd use the Date object appropriately

Comment: `new Date()` creates a Date object representing the current date and time. [What is the best way to initialize a JavaScript Date to midnight?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3894048) tells you how to set midnight on a Date. Then you can use [Function to get yesterday's date in Javascript in format DD/MM/YYYY](//stackoverflow.com/q/16686640) to get yesterday. It's all here on Stack Overflow, you just need to look.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ive set using the links provided but they only set between today and tommorow. Ive updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You'll kick yourself. As you know,

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

creates a date for 00:00:00 today. For yesterday, subtract 24 hours (set the hours to -24):

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(-24,0,0,0))
```

E.g.

```js
console.log(`Today: ${new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))},
Yesterday: ${new Date(new Date().setHours(-24,0,0,0))}`);
```